# How to use foreach library without loading it

Tags: r, foreach

Is there any way to use the *foreach* package without loading it? I want to use it in another package and preferably I do not want to load it.
If I simply write

```
 foreach::foreach(i = 1:3) %do% sqrt(i)
```

then I get the following error.

```
Error: could not find function "%do%"
```

Any idea or suggestion? The reason for doing so is that I want to use the `.combine` option of `foreach()` to combine the outputs of *data.table* class together.

Comment: Why don't you want to load it in your package?

Comment: Hm, not sure. The main person for the package I am adding some functions wants us not to load any package as much as possible. So if there is any way to avoid I would prefer that.

Comment: @RichardScriven I can see that it is not working. So there is no way to use it without loading?

Comment: Is the foreach functionality used anywhere else in the code or just in what you're adding?

Comment: In just what I am adding

Comment: @RichardScriven why do you say it is ridiculous? Does it change anything in terms of speed or ?!!

Comment: It's just abnormal.  But you can do it that way if you want to.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It works.

Comment: @newbie just talk with the project leader.  Have them add the package as a "suggests" and load the package at the time you need it.  Seems like a reasonable approach to me.

Comment: If you use the functionality of foreach you really need to at least add it to the packages in Suggests.

Comment: We add all the used packages in the Suggests. We are just trying not to load them, and instead address to them. But I will ask. Thanks @Dason

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose you could do

```
foreach::"%do%"(foreach::foreach(i = 1:3), sqrt(i))
```

But the proper way would be to import these functions (or the entire *foreach* package) into your package by adding the following lines in your NAMESPACE file.

```
importFrom(foreach, %do%)
importFrom(foreach, foreach)
```